# Android apk install failed

Tags: android, installation, signed

I use Android studio generate signed apk,but it can not install on Android 6.0 .My jdk is 1.8.0 .
I can use adb install the apk.

This the log.

```
/PackageManager: Verification timed out for file:///storage/emulated/0/Tencent/QQfile_recv/app-release.apk /PackageManager: Continuing with installation of file:///storage/emulated/0/Tencent/QQfile_recv/app-release.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify that no duplicate dependencies